# String.contains behaving oddly with ArrayList

Tags: java, string, search, arraylist, string-comparison

SOLVED.  The answer was to replace

```
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        lowerField = results.get(i)[2].toLowerCase();

        if(lowerField.equals(search));
        {
            finalResults.add(results.get(i));
        }
    }
```

with

```
            for(String[] searchItems : results) 
            {
                lowerField = searchItems[2].toLowerCase();
                if(lowerField.equals(search)) 
                { // or lowerField.contains(search)
                    finalResults.add(searchItems);
                }
            }
```

Seems that, for some reason, the original add(results.get(i)) statement was confusing something somewhere, whereas the add(searchItems) statement plays nicely.

To assist anyone else having a similar issue, please help me clean up and clarify this question to the proper standards so it can assist others.

CORRECT WORKING code to match sample in the original question:

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> searchLog(ArrayList<String> searchMe, String action)
{
    //ArrayList full of String arrays to break up and hold each line of the passed ArrayList
    ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    //Same structure as above, intended to hold the lines matching the user's search criteria
    ArrayList<String[]> finalResults = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    //String variable used to hold the current field we're searching "toLowerCase"
    String lowerField = null;

    //For each string in the input ArrayList...
    for (String str : searchMe)
    {
        //Add each line (after splitting it into an array) to the "results" ArrayList
        results.add(str.split("~"));
    }

    //If the user chose to search on "Partner ID"
    if (action.equals("ptnr"))
    {
        //Print line with criteria and search field
        System.out.println("Searching on Partner ID for " + search + "....");

        //For each line (string array) in the "results" ArrayList
        for(String[] searchItems : results) 
        {
            //Set "lowerField" equal to the current line (string array) sub 1 where Partner ID is located, and set it toLowerCase
            lowerField = searchItems[1].toLowerCase();
            //If the cell we're searching contains the user's search criteria
            if(lowerField.contains(search)) 
            { 
                //Then add the whole line to the finalResults ArrayList that we will return from this function.
                finalResults.add(searchItems);
            }
        }
    }
    return finalResults;
}
```

Thanks again for your help!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ORIGINAL QUESTION~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ok, I've got a function that's supposed to go through an ArrayList and search on a particular piece of each array in the list.  Upon finding a match, the function adds that entire array to a second ArrayList full of the search results.

I ALSO tried simply removing anything that DID NOT match the search criteria from the original ArrayList to save the memory of having a second one unnecessarily and achieved the same incorrect result that way as well.  Function to follow:

NOTE:  SEARCH is a piece of user input (stored in a public static "global") that has already been set "toLowerCase" in my Main function before being used here.

```
    public static ArrayList<String[]> searchLog(ArrayList<String> searchMe, String action)
{
    ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ArrayList<String[]> finalResults = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String lowerField = null;

    for (String str : searchMe)
    {
        results.add(str.split("~"));
    }

    if (action.equals("ptnr"))
    {
        System.out.println("Searching on Partner ID for " + search + "....");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size()-1; i++)
        {
            lowerField = results.get(i)[1].toLowerCase();

            if(lowerField.equals(search))
            {
                //System.out.println("one added");
                finalResults.add(results.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    return finalResults;
}
```

I've tried using lowerField.equals(search), lowerField.contains(search), and lowerField.matches(search), to include several variations and string manipulations thereof.

My ideal outcome would be to use "contains," as the "timestamp" the user can search on is impractically specific and contains more info than just a date and time they can realistically search on.

Now for my results.

When I run the function and search on "ptnr," my results are correct.  When I search on either of the other two, my results return the correct NUMBER of entries (to include the correct number of REMOVED when I had a println indicating that an entry that didn't match had been removed) but the entries that ARE retained and displayed are a mixed bag of non-matching lines as well as matches together.  Again, the NUMBER of lines printed out is correct, but the lines themselves aren't the matching lines only.

This is the function that calls the searchLog():

```
if(srv)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("============================= SEARCH RESULTS ===================================");
            System.out.println("");

            ArrayList<String[]> results = searchLog(line, "ptnr");

            for (int x = 0; x < results.size(); x++)
                System.out.println(results.get(x)[0] + " " + results.get(x)[1] + " " + results.get(x)[2] + " " + results.get(x)[3] + " " + results.get(x)[4] + " ms." );

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("============================= END SEARCH RESULTS ===================================");
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Above, "line" is the ArrayList I'm searching through and "srv" in the "if" block is a global boolean set by user input.  All of that is working currently, just not the search and filter itself.

Thanks in advance guys, and let me know if you need any more info!

EDIT:  Yeah, I know I used a bubble sort...  Let the flaming begin haha, but it's been a while and this is a time-sensitive util for a new job.  On the server running this util, and with the minimal amount of data processed (300 lines per run), the bubble still accomplishes its goal in the blink of a cursor.  :)

EDIT 2:  Sample input data:

```
2013-10-15 08:28:31,514~stQAEFV~establishAgreementSummary~2~5234 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:22,442~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1776 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:37,333~sfRPDesktop~modifyParty~2~1744 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:14,719~sgITL~retrieveParty~2~1702 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:27,755~sgFASTOL~establishParty~2~1682 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:39,677~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1679 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:55,768~sgBLD~searchAgreementSummary~2~1495 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:46,272~sgCSCWB~searchAgreementSummary~1~1402 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:49,660~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1395 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:39,547~sgHERYN~searchAgreementSummary~1~1341 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:47,028~sgCSCWB~retrieveCustomerProfile~1~1323 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:29,795~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1296 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:44,520~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1290 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:04,398~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1284 ms.
```

Output when searched on "ptnr" working correctly, then output when searching on timestamp for "y" (which should not ever produce a result...) returning ALL rows:

```
============================= SEARCH RESULTS ===================================

Searching on Partner ID for sgfastol....
before sort
after sort
2013-10-15 08:28:22,442 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1776 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:27,755 sgFASTOL establishParty 2  1682 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:29,795 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1296 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:04,398 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1284 ms.





============================= SEARCH RESULTS ===================================

Searching on Timestamp for y....
before sort
after sort
2013-10-15 08:28:31,514 stQAEFV establishAgreementSummary 2  5234 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:22,442 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1776 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:37,333 sfRPDesktop modifyParty 2  1744 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:14,719 sgITL retrieveParty 2  1702 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:27,755 sgFASTOL establishParty 2  1682 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:39,677 sfRPDesktop retrieveParty 2  1679 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:55,768 sgBLD searchAgreementSummary 2  1495 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:46,272 sgCSCWB searchAgreementSummary 1  1402 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:49,660 sfRPDesktop retrieveParty 2  1395 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:39,547 sgHERYN searchAgreementSummary 1  1341 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:47,028 sgCSCWB retrieveCustomerProfile 1  1323 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:29,795 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1296 ms.
2013-10-15 08:27:44,520 sfRPDesktop retrieveParty 2  1290 ms.
2013-10-15 08:28:04,398 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2  1284 ms.
```

Finally, I know it's sloppy.  I apologize.  I've literally put three hours into it, one of which has been trying to figure out this search.  It's a unix util (not very familiar with unix) written in Java (I'm a .NET dev), so I'm a little out of my element.  Cleanup will take place once I get it functioning.  This is simply a "rough draft" if you will, intended only to show the feasibility (or lack thereof) of a larger project.  Thank you for all of your responses though!  Specific comments to follow each answer.

-Tom

Comment: You've shown a lot of code, but it's not at all clear that all of it is relevant. Why are you omitting the last element of `finalResults` and `results` when you're iterating though? (Your `for` loops are of the form `for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`.)

Comment: It would be very helpful to have an example of the actual input values into the searchLog method, along with the expected results and the actual results. If you could provide a full example of the input and the search string, we could help you figure this out.

Comment: @JonSkeet fixed the iterator, not sure what I was doing there.  Didn't affect my search results.

Comment: @axiopisty Please see my recent edit, and thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after both of the edits made to the OP it is still not clear what the expected and actual results are. Nor is it clear what the question is. It is very hard to answer an unclear, unasked, question. But based on the example code, Here is a sample test program that might get you closer to what you're looking for... maybe?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question19369420 {
    private static String search;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        search = "sgfastol";

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:31,514~stQAEFV~establishAgreementSummary~2~5234 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:22,442~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1776 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:37,333~sfRPDesktop~modifyParty~2~1744 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:14,719~sgITL~retrieveParty~2~1702 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:27,755~sgFASTOL~establishParty~2~1682 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:39,677~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1679 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:55,768~sgBLD~searchAgreementSummary~2~1495 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:46,272~sgCSCWB~searchAgreementSummary~1~1402 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:49,660~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1395 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:39,547~sgHERYN~searchAgreementSummary~1~1341 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:47,028~sgCSCWB~retrieveCustomerProfile~1~1323 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:29,795~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1296 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:27:44,520~sfRPDesktop~retrieveParty~2~1290 ms.");
        input.add("2013-10-15 08:28:04,398~sgFASTOL~retrieveParty~2~1284 ms.");

        String action = "ptnr";
        ArrayList<String[]> results = null;
        if ("time".equals(action)) {
            results = searchLogs(input, 0);
        } else if ("ptnr".equals(action)) {
            results = searchLogs(input, 1);
        } else if ("srv".equals(action)) {
            results = searchLogs(input, 2);
        }

        if (results != null) {
            System.out.println("before sort");
            print(results);
            Collections.sort(results, createComparator(4));
            System.out.println("after sort");
            print(results);
        }

    }

    public static Comparator<String[]> createComparator(final int field) {
        return new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
                return a[field].compareTo(b[field]);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void print(List<String[]> list) {
        for (String[] item : list) {
            System.out.println(String.format("  %s %s %s %s %s ms.", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4]));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String[]> searchLogs(List<String> input, int index) {
        System.out.println("Searching on Partner ID for " + search + "....");
        ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str : input) {
            results.add(str.split("~"));
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> finalResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String[] searchItems : results) {
            String lowerField = searchItems[index].toLowerCase();
            if (lowerField.equals(search)) { // or lowerField.contains(search)
                finalResults.add(searchItems);
            }
        }
        return finalResults;
    }
}
```

Here is the output from running the program:

```
Searching on Partner ID for sgfastol....
before sort
  2013-10-15 08:28:22,442 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1776 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:28:27,755 sgFASTOL establishParty 2 1682 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:27:29,795 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1296 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:28:04,398 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1284 ms. ms.
after sort
  2013-10-15 08:28:04,398 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1284 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:27:29,795 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1296 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:28:27,755 sgFASTOL establishParty 2 1682 ms. ms.
  2013-10-15 08:28:22,442 sgFASTOL retrieveParty 2 1776 ms. ms.
```

Comment: I just tried your code for iterating through each "searchItem" in "results" and it worked like a charm...  I have no idea why that makes a difference, but it does!  Thanks for your help and pointers, I'm in the process of going through and simplifying the function as you suggested now!  :D

Comment: In my second edit, the "correct" response was to return ONLY data that matched the search criteria.  Actual response was that ALL data was returned for some reason.  As stated in my comment above, it ended up being a simple fix.  Something about my "iterate through, compare, add if equal" block did not work, whereas YOUR block did.  Editing my original post to show the code that functions properly.

Comment: The sort was a non-issue.  It was simply there as a luxury and had no bearing on the issue I was having.  I apologize for the confusion and have removed it from my original (and the working) code in my question.  Please refer to the original post for cleaned up, commented, working code to clear up any confusion about what I was trying to accomplish.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the interfaces like `java.util.List` instead of `ArrayList` to make your application more flexible. Your text indicated that you are working with some kind of timestamp why are you not working with `java.util.Date` or some other object that has something to do with time?

Why are you just looping for `results.size()-1`? This leads to a number of `results.size()-2` runs. The correct approach to set loop end is either `i < result.size()` or `i <= result.size()-1`.

Could you provide some input and output examples for your bug?

Comment: Please see my edit for input and output examples.

As far as the List and Date suggestions, blame my newbie-ness.  I haven't touched Java for a long time and this is my first foray back into the language.  I'll look into using a List instead as I wasn't even aware of the functional differences, to be honest.

Date isn't practical because the Date field I'm processing also holds a unique process ID that is tied to the date (not unique, except to each timestamp) that I don't want to process separately.

Also didn't want to set up different simple formats for each log style with different format.